# I got errors in flutter app,but did't show the error filename and line number in debug mode

Tags: flutter, debugging, runtime-error

[The following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfOyq.png)

The same errors are shown with the filename and line number on right side in another system.What I have to do to get those file name and line number

I have tried to change the debug console settings in visual studio code.But it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this error generally comes due to the issue in widget tree for example when you put a Listview inside a single child scrollable, as it is not able to get the height of list view.

Without seeing the code I cannot exactly tell you where the error is, if you can share the code I can figure it out.

A quick solution to this is as it says 'BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.', is that you wrap the widget inside the listview, singlechildscroll view or a column inside a container and give them a height.